# fetch the path of an image stored in gallery after camera capture

Tags: android, android-image

I am opening camera using following code

```
Intent captureImageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

cordova.setActivityResultCallback(this);

cordova.getActivity().startActivityForResult(captureImageIntent,RESULT_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
```

and inside `onActivityResult` i am trying to get the `path of the image` that is stored in gallery , so that i can return it back to the web page.

here what i have tried so far

```
Uri uri = intent.getData(); // doesnt work
```

i tried to use `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` but in that case i am getting null intent.

```
captureImageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mPhotoUri);
```

so can anyone tell me how can i fetch the path ?

EDIT

```
 String fileName = "temp.jpg";  
 contentValues values = new ContentValues();  
 values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName); 

            Uri mPhotoUri = cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Comment: can you please post how to get mPhotoUri ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana view the edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define custom methods for set and get captured image path :

```
private String imgPath;

public Uri setImageUri() {
   // Store image in dcim
   File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".jpg");
   Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
   imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
   return imgUri;
}

public String getImagePath() {
   return imgPath;
}
```

Set image uri to EXTRA_OUTPUT using capture intent :

```
captureImageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
```

Get captured image bitamp from decoded capture image path :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
       if (requestCode == RESULT_CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
           imgUserImage.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(getImagePath()));
       }
   }
}

public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
   try {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale = 1;
        while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
        scale *= 2;
        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
 return null;
}
```